# Cruising with Pets

Tags: cruising, pets

We vacation pretty much exclusively by camper/recreational vehicle, so we can take our pets with us.  We have be considering going on cruise.

Are there oceanship cruises that are pet friendly?

Comment: What kind of pets?

Comment: @DJClayworth in my personal case it is a [house rabbit](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8122/is-a-bedroom-enough-space-for-a-bunny-to-be-happy/8130#8130) but the question was intended to be general.  Experience teaches me that personal contact with pet friendly accommodations is required addr4ess the rabbit specific question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick google of "Pet friendly cruise" brings up [Which Ships Offer Pet Friendly Cruises?](https://www.cruisecritic.com/articles.cfm?ID=2053)  which states

> When it comes to cruise ships that allow pets, there's only one:
>   Cunard's Queen Mary 2

But then goes on to state

> .. you can bring your dog or cat, but that doesn't mean your fuzzy
>   family members will be able to snuggle with you in your cabin. They'll
>   be confined to their own digs in an onboard kennel on Deck 12, where
>   dedicated crew members feed, walk and clean up after them in addition
>   to lavishing them with treats and toys

Every other link seems to show day cruises only and I don't think that is what you are looking for.

I also found [Is There Such a Thing as a Pet-Friendly Cruise?](https://www.travelandleisure.com/blogs/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-pet-friendly-cruise), and the key quote from this is

> The main reasons other cruise lines don’t allow animals on board:
>   hygiene—ships have strict sanitation codes—and port regulations. Each
>   country has its own entry requirements for animals, so navigating
>   multiple-country cruises would be a headache for ships and pet owners
>   alike.

Finally, [Want To Bring Your Pet On A Cruise? Pet Friendly Cruises](https://usserviceanimals.org/blog/pet-friendly-cruises) talks from the perspective of service animals on ships (and is basically the same advice as the previous links).  But as you are talking about pets, the advice there is moot.

Comment: BTW, I think one could bring pet on QM2 on not really "cruise" travels, but just on transatlantic travels.